# How do you get the type of an entire function, not just Parameters or ReturnType

Tags: typescript

I am looking for a way to get the entire type of a given function.

For example:

```
const AddOne = (a) => a + 1

type Example = FunctionType<typeof AddOne>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
export type FunctionType<T extends (...args: any) => any> = (...a: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T>
```

Comment: Why not just `type Example = typeof AddOne`. Your type just acts as an identity for a function signature.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand the use case.  If you want the "entire type", then you want `type FunctionType<T> = T`. If you want to restrict it to function types I suppose you could have `type FunctionType<T extends (...a:any)=>any> = T` but it's still just the identity type function.